# How to clear the MGT PeoplePicker in react hooks SPFx web part?

Tags: react-hooks, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I need to clear the the `PeoplePicker` after use.

```js
<PeoplePicker
  selectedPeople={addedMembers}
  selectionMode={"multiple"}
  show-max={50}
  selectionChanged={onPeoplePickerChanged}
/>;
```

So I set `addedMembers` to `[]` but it does not work.

I saw an answer involving ref [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/279982/clear-the-people-picker-control-on-button-click) but it uses a class and I only know hooks.
Anyone can help?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect we have a rendering bug here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-x1xlm7?file=App.tsx 
This stackblitz shows the array being cleared but the rendered display of selected users only updates to be cleared visually when you focus to the input box again.

Comment: I tried to implement the ref logic with hooks https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zayywf?file=App.tsx but it does not work. So @GavinB you thing I should report a bug to MGT?

Comment: I think I got a solution: see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zayywf?file=App.tsx

Comment: If you could add an issue it would be helpful. Using a ref to set focus and trigger that behavior is a clever workaround, but it's definitely a bug in our implementation.

Answer (score 1):

See example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zayywf?file=App.tsx

make  a ref  `const ppl = React.useRef(null);`

add to the `<PeoplePicker ref={ppl}`

then when you want to clear set the selectedPeople to [] and run `ppl.current.focus();`

Hope it helps others